# 433 MHz crystal 3 feet pinout?

Tags: oscillator, crystal, pinout

What are the pins A, B, C of this 433 MHz crystal oscillator?

[image: pinout]

https://nexelectronics.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/433-MHZ-CRYSTAL-OSCILLATOR-1.jpg

I suppose these are input, output, ground. Could you explain or give me a link to datasheet on internet? I researched, because I have just obtained this crystal and want to test on project, but could not find and figure out which pin serves for what.

Comment: It is probably a SAW (surface acoustic wave) resonator, not a crystal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is called "TO-39" or "TO39". I'm sure you'll find a lot of matching products if you google "R433 TO-39" or "R433 TO39".

As for the pinout, `A` must be the ground connection (think of it like chassis ground), and `B` and `C` are the crystal element pins.